How to derive the Copula of $(X,Y)$ for X continuous random variable and $Y=X^{-1}$?
I didn't solve them in the exam and I still can't figure out how to solve it correctly.

For $X\sim U(-1,1)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{X}$, derive the Copula of $(X,Y)$ and what is its uniqueness.
For $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{X}$, derive the Copula of $(X,Y)$.

In the both case, our $X$ is continuous and could takes $0$ as its value which seems to be problem to me that Y is not continuous. One can not directly use the formula
$$C(u_1,\dots,u_d)=F(F_1^{-1}(u_1),\dots,F_d^{-1}(u_d)) $$
where $F$ is a $d$-dim. distribution function with continuous marginal c.d.f.s $F_i$ and C is uniquely determined by this formula.
But I do not know how to handle the case when $X$ takes value $0$ with $Y=\frac{1}{0}$.
I was wondering if we can construct functions $f(x)=x$ non-decreasing and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ non-increasing such that $(X,Y)=(f(X),g(X))$ in distribution and then use the countermonotonicity Copula but it didn't work.
Does anyone have a hint or point out where I have understood mistakenly?
Update:
for the first one, I got $C(u_1,u_2)=u_1+u_2-1$, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Hint: what is $\Pr(X=0)$?

@whuber HI! for our case it would be 0.

Then it's not relevant, is it?

@whuber do you mean we can directly use the formula or are our function f and g well defined to have the countermonotonictiy property?

Unless I am confused, one can work this out "in head" (or indeed via simulation, which almost lays out the algebra in any case), and so see what more formal algebraic steps should be needed. It might help to start the first problem with a simpler case ... $X\sim U(0,1)$ with $Y$ as above and then jump from that (hopefully immediately obvious)  to the actual problem in "1."  which only adds a very small wrinkle. Case 2. may then be easier to see as well
